# php - при запуске скрипта каждый раз новый параметр

Tags: php

Подскажите как можно сделать на php так чтоб при каждом запуске скрипта выбирался другой параметр?

Есть вот такая строчка http://192.168.0.15/?R7_off она преключает на ардуинке реле в одно положение, а вот такая в другое http://192.168.0.15/?R7_on

Нужно чтоб когда запускаю php скрипт каждый раз _on менялась на _off

Comment: Мало деталей. Как вы запускаете php? Веб-сервер или CLI? П данной ссылки отрабатывает код php или сама ардуина?

Comment: Веб сервер. Через кнопку в WEB нажимаю и отрабатывается любой php Скрипт который занесу в нее. На ардуине только web server который понимает два состояния _off и _on.

Comment: привидете пример php кода и кнопки

Comment: Это будет сложно сделать это целая система и не понятно как и откуда это взять. Это система majordom. Кнопка отработает любой php который внего засунем. Нужен только код, который будет записывать (куда нибудь - в переменную, в файл) уровень последнего запуска и запускать и посылать другую ссылку. Например: если предидущий запуск скрипта был запрос на адрес с _on То тогда делаем запрос по ссылке на _off, добавляем запись в файл или переменную о последнем переходе по сылке с  _off

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите сделать тогглер, самый простой вариант, прошлое состояние сохранять в файл и при следующем запуске его инвертировать, второй вариант, использовать кеш, например такой http://php.net/manual/ru/book.apc.php

Comment: _"Это расширение считается неподдерживаемым и мертвым"_ © [справка](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.apc.php)

Comment: Я просто уже давно не пхпшник, но суть я думаю донёс, состояние надо сохранить, вариантов у вас много

Comment: можно еще запрашивать его, если таковое поддерживается. Это было бы надежнее.

Comment: Ну да, можно было бы запрашивать у самой ардуино текущее состояние

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Поизучаю. Сам то же php не знаю.

Comment: Я раньше писал на нем бекенд, а щас на java

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, эти приведенные в вопросе адреса обрабатывает `php` и на странице есть кнопка, то почему бы просто не менять URL кнопки (ссылки)  на странице в зависимости от гет параметра?

```
<a href="http://192.168.0.15/?R7_<?= isset(_GET['R7_off']) ? 'on' : 'off' ?>">Переключатель</a>
```

Comment: Это система majordom и кнопку менять не вариант, нужен просто код на php - скрипт. Любой php шный скрипт кнопка отработает. Там кнопки в системе зашиты и ничего кроме как отработка скрипта не делают.

Answer (score 0):

С моем представлении код должен быть что-то типо этого, но я не знаю как это в php описать.

```
  if (laststat = '_on')
to file_get_contents('http://192.168.0.15/?R7_' + '_on');
else
file_get_contents('http://192.168.0.15/?R7_' + '_off');
//Записываем в переменную последний запуск
set = '_off'
```

Comment: Хотя может да же проще на arduino то же самое сделать.